# applying statistics in "filling in" a data set?

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, references, dataset, missing-data

Let me first say that my professional role is that of a mid level OLAP/OLTP developer (lesser experience with OLTP). Ive only had business statistics in school many years ago and I am currently taking the time out to review statistics from the beginning as I'm interested in data science.

I have a project - I want to achieve an agricultural related data set to demonstrate reporting technologies off of and perhaps later apply R, data science and machine learning concepts to. I currently have 2 years of solid, real world data originating from a farming enterprise operation; revenues, expenses, production, fertilizer etc. However it abruptly starts and stops. Id like to continue/extend the data set to make it larger by leveraging the relationships and trends present in the existing dataset, perhaps even create a data set before (pre-period). Not knowing where to start, I briefly discussed this task to a SQL developer associate at work who has more recent exposure to statistics than I, and because of the existence of data that I have that possess relevant associations/relationships/correlations (not sure if I am phrasing that correctly), they mentioned using statistics as a tool, brought up Bayesian statistics and some other related nomenclature.

I need more guidance here, my question to the community - can anyone point me in the right direction? What (stat) tools I should consider using for this task? What direction to go in? Specifically how and what statistical applications I should consider?

Also - in addition to this one, what are good (business) statistics related blogs and forums for someone in my position wanting to add to my skill set and for support and guidance on such a project?

Comment: Not all people here will be familiar with acronyms like OLAP and OLTP. Please expand them on first use.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do missing value imputation in time series.

Comment: Is this purely an academic exercise ? How much confidence would you put in predicting 1,2,3,4,5 years into the past or future, given you only have 2 years data and that the business is influenced strongly by climate, pest and disease and demand variation ?  http://www.kdnuggets.com/ is one place you might look for data mining related resources.